# Strange Java behaviour. Ternary operator

Tags: java, operator-keyword, ternary

Why does this code work?

```
Float testFloat = null;
Float f = true ? null : 0f;
```

And why does this throw an exception?

```
Float testFloat = null;
Float f = true ? testFloat : 0f;
```

But the strangest thing is that this code also runs successfully without any exceptions:

```
Float testFloat = null;
Float f = testFloat;
```

It seems that the ternary operator of Java changes the behaviour. Can anyone explain why this is, please?

Comment: I run it with JDK 7u25 and it didn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: The third code can't throw exceptions: you're declaring one variable, set it to null, then declaring another one and setting it to the value of the first one which is null. No exceptions could be thrown

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The behaviour is specified in [JLS - Conditional Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then **the type of the conditional expression is T**.

Emphasis mine. So, in the 2<sup>nd</sup> case:

```
Float f = true ? testFloat : 0f;
```

Since 3rd operand is primitive type(`T`), the type of the expression would be float type - `T`. So, *unboxing*  *testFloat* which is currently a `null` reference, to `float` will result in *NPE*.

---

As for the 1<sup>st</sup> case, relevant part is the last one:

> Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2 respectively. Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1, and let T2 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S2. The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2) (§15.12.2.7).

So, according to this:

```
null type - S1
float     - S2

null type - T1 (boxing null type gives null type)
Float     - T2 (float boxed to Float)
```

and then type of conditional expression becomes - `Float`. No unboxing of `null` needed, and hence no `NPE`.

Comment: Oh... I got it now! Thx u so much for the answer!

Comment: I couldn't find the exact rule why `true ? null : 0f` is ok, though. Can you pinpoint that part in the JLS? Or would that simply be "If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the null type), then that is the type of the conditional expression.", where `0f` is boxed to `Float`?

Comment: @Heuster. Let me check out.

Comment: That's a nice explanation

Comment: I have NullPointerException with this case, can you explain this :
value != null ? value.toString() : "null"       Thanks